# "Sign In" button of yahoo mail is not clicked by WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, yahoo, yahoo-mail

I am using Selenium WebDriver(a.k.a. Selenium 2) with Java. For clicking "Sign In" button of Yahoo mail, I have written the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(".save")).click();
```

But unfortunately, it is not working. What's the wrong with my code? Can anybody help me?

Comment: can you provide some more code and error ?

Comment: @Muna: Was "Sign In" button visible on the browser? During execution, if browser is not maximized "Sign In" button might not be visible and WebDriver might not be located/identified the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the browser is not maximized during execution of the test, please maximize the browser by using the following line of code:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Then, "Sign In" button would be visible on the page and hopefully it should work.

Comment: There is an alternate solution to do scroll down so that Sign In button would be displayed/visible on the page and it would work. For scrolling: ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("scroll(0,250);");